# String types not allowed (at 'blue' with value '')

Tags: android, build, android-support-library, android-build

I am getting following error in appcompat-v7 library building the project.

```
    Error:(380, 5) String types not allowed (at 'blue' with value '').
\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\values\values.xml
```

appcompat-v7 library values.xml file where this error is occuring:

```
   <!-- this line --> <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult" parent=""> 



<item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
                <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
                <item name="android:textColorHint">?android:textColorHint</item>
            </style>
```

I have latest version of Android Studio (2.0 Preview 7) and appcompat-v7 library.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion  23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId "com.ms.sensors"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 7
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        compileOptions.with {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
            }
        }
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "sensorgraph"
        cppFlags.add("-Werror")
        ldLibs.addAll(["log", "GLESv2", "android"])
        stl = "c++_static"
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
        }
        create("x86-32") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
        }
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa

        // build one including all cpu architectures
        create("all")
    }
}
dependencies {
    //        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

My style.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: post your `values.xml` file

Comment: @UmaKanth do you mean xml file from v7 library?

Comment: I didn't modified it. This file is under build folder which i automatically generated everytime during build.

Comment: I have even tried to clean the project and rebuild it.

Comment: Can you post your styles.xml here? I had faced a same issue and the problem was in styles.xml

Comment: @ObscureGeek i have updated the post. Please take a look into it.

Comment: Apparently you have not made the same error that I had made. However, are you sure that the line the error is coming and you have pointed out is same? The error message is saying something different. I believe the line number you have mentioned in values.xml is around 1741 and not 380. Can you post the exact line?

Comment: @ObscureGeek error is coming on same line. How did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You assign empty value to 'blue'

open your color.xml then search for 'blue' and check you assigned color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="blue"></color> <!-- must add valid value -->
</resources>
```