# downgrading from sdk 23 to 22 android

Tags: android, build, sdk, compiler-errors, version

I decided to reduce my api level from 23 to 22. To begin with, I downloaded android studio with the latest 23 API installed. I installed the 22 API now but I don't know if I installed the other stuff like:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Can't find where to look if these are installed... So this is how my manifest looks like:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22 //changed this, used to be 23
buildToolsVersion "22.0.0" //changed this also, but I don't know if it's installed....

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 11
    versionName "2.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'libs'] } }
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:1.0.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'//changed this also, but I don't know if it's installed....
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'//changed this also, but I don't know if it's installed....
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
}
```

So when I try to sync it gives me this crap:

C:\Users\jonathan\AndroidStudioProjects\TrashOmeter\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\jonathan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

[image]

[image]

How do I get it to compile with 22 sdk correctly???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to CommonsWare I found the answer. I had to change the google play dependency to a lower version. So in gradle I changed:

From:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
```

To:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.3.0'
```

Answer (score 6):

You wont be able to downgrade from SDK 23 to 22 if have already uploaded your apk (sdk 23) on google play. Store will not let you.

I have already done this mistake and now my APP is disadvantaged compared to my competitors who didnt made this mistake.

So DONT USE SDK 23, it will make your users angry if they have to enable LOCATION for your app (access to wifi channel list is main purpose of my app)

Comment: I have same problem Adam, i have uploaded a app with targetSdkVersion 23. not i want to downgrage it to 21/20, when i try to update that app on play store. it gives me error.

Comment: Finally, google will require newest SDK on google play. So if someone upgraded app by mistake in the past, in the future will not be as disadvantaged as now. Of course, if the app is not updated it can still use old SDK 22. source: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html

Answer (score 1):

> I decided to reduce my api level from 23 to 22

Given the comments in your `build.gradle` file, you appear to mean that you reduced your `compileSdkVersion` to 22.

I have no idea why you would do that.

*Raising* the `compileSdkVersion` to a newer level is perfectly reasonable and will be required to use some newer versions of dependencies (let alone any new references from your own code). I know of no problems in modern Android development that are solved by *reducing* `compileSdkVersion`. You seem to be causing yourself pain for no actual benefit.

> I installed the 22 API now but I don't know if I installed the other stuff like

If you have an up-to-date "Android Repository" in the SDK Manager, then you have older versions of the Android Support libraries.

> //changed this also, but I don't know if it's installed...

If you have an up-to-date "Build Tools" in the SDK Manager, then you have older versions of the Android Support libraries.

> So when I try to sync it gives me this crap:

That "crap" is because you decided to change your `compileSdkVersion` to 22, yet not change your dependencies to similarly older versions. Your current dependency versions are written with references to things from API Level 23 (in this case, resources) and need `compileSdkVersion` 23.

> How do I get it to compile with 22 sdk correctly?

Reduce the versions of your dependencies to ones that pre-date the existence of API Level 23. For those that you are getting from Maven Central or JCenter (e.g., `facebook-android-sdk`), you can probably find out dates of artifacts from their Web interface, and try to find ones from August 2015 or earlier. For the rest... you're on your own.

Or, change your `compileSdkVersion` back to 23.

Comment: i had similar issue, and this error occurred when i change  compileSdkVersion to Google Inc.:Google APIs:23. How to fix this issue? I am already using the latest build tools, Studio, libraries and gradle version.

Comment: facebook only requires API 15 so it's fine. I'm not sure about the rest but when I try to sync up the app gradle file it always wants to change my appcompat and design dependencies back to 23 I don't know why... I have to manual change it back to 22 over and over again...

Comment: @Malwinder: I am not aware of any modern reason to have that `compileSdkVersion` value. Using `Google APIs` build targets were for Maps V1, and that API was discontinued years ago.

Comment: @CommonsWare oh. But my project had this version by default when i created it.

Comment: @JonathanVukadinovic: One of your dependencies has a transitive dependency specifying a higher version of those support libraries. Running a Gradle dependency report should help you isolate which dependency is doing that. That would allow you to focus on finding an older version of that dependency that does not rely on the newer support libraries.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you please check this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990485/string-types-not-allowed-at-blue-with-value

Comment: @JonathanVukadinovic: No, you are overriding it to say that it is transitive (I am not quite sure why). A dependency can have its own dependencies. For example, `play-services` pulls in a couple of dozen dependencies on its own. This is why I suggested that you run a Gradle dependency report. Or, more simply, revert back to `compileSdkVersion 23`.

Comment: I did that because it was in the instructions to integrate tweet-composer. Maybe I'll take it out and see if it works